# Though ran for for a while but Program has stopped working?

Tags: c++, nested-loops

There is neither anything wrong nor it is an infinity loop then why this is happening? I am trying to analyze but I couldn't find out the reason as I am real beginner of c++ language! :) Thank you in advance! Have a good day!

[image: 1]

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    char UPPERCASE[27];
    char LOWERCASE[27];
    int j = 97;
    for (int i = 65; i <= 90 && j <= 122; i++ && j++) {
        UPPERCASE[i] = i;
        LOWERCASE[j] = j;
        cout << UPPERCASE[i];
        cout << LOWERCASE[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You created an array with 27 elements, right? Then how do you want to access 66th element of it?

Comment: I have used the concept of ACII table. And If I was wrong then how has the compiler built it?

Comment: As Matthieu mentioned in his answer, a compiler should produce a warning if you enable them. And C++ has the attitude "If programmer want to, they are free to shoot themselves in their foot". If you go into Undefined Behaviour sector (and access of array out-of-bounds is UB), the program can do absolutely everything, including doing something seemingly okay or [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). You can use for example `std::vector` and access elements with `at()` method, then you'll have an exception with wrong access.

Comment: @Mr.Khan The compiler lets you do a lot of things, which lead to _undefined behavior_ though. At best you can expect warnings.

Comment: @Mr.Khan *And If I was wrong then how has the compiler built it?* -- C++ has no array bounds checking.  If you want to access index `-12` or index `45244`, go ahead and do so.  What will happen if you do that, that is a different story.  In your case, you blew up your program.

Answer (score 1):

The "&&" in for increment portion is very confusing.

I have rewritten this using only one index.

The original code uses a base index of 65 and 97.  However, the array itself only is allocated with 27 cells.  This will not work.

To solve this, I allocated 26 cells for each array (only 26 letters in the English alphabet) and then put 'A' and 'a' in cell [0] of each array.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    char upperCaseArray[26];
    char lowerCaseArray[26];
    for(int i=0; i < 26; i++){
        upperCaseArray[i]=(char) i + 'A';
        lowerCaseArray[i]=(char) i + 'a';
        std::cout << upperCaseArray[i];
        std::cout << lowerCaseArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The values of each cell should be the '65', '66', and so forth (i.e. 'A', 'B' ...).  But, we can use the actual letter 'A' instead of the decimal value of 65, avoiding a mistake caused by writing down the wrong value.

So, we add the index of the cell to the value of the letter and store that, rather than using the value as the index.

I have reduced this to only one index, used in both arrays, so we do not need i and j.

Comment: Strongly recommend null-terminating those arrays.

Comment: Prefer using character literals (constants) to their decimal ASCII encodings.  I've memorized the table in hex, but the decimal values require extra conversion.  Character literals, such as `'A'` would make the program more readable (feel free to improve the OP's code).

Comment: See also `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.

Comment: Also, don't use `using namespace std;`.  Either list specific items from `std`, e.g. `using std::cout`, or use the `std` prefix:  `std::cout`.  Remember that `using namespace std;` brings in the entire namespace (which increases the probability of naming conflicts).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  Thank you for the kind suggestions.  I always hesitate to modify every line of an answer, but you are correct.  I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @user4581301:  I usually null-terminate c-strings, but have never been in the habit of null-terminating arrays.  By null terminating them, you could pass the arrays to be printed as c-strings of the alphabet.  I suppose it might also help catch a but in case someone tried to access memory beyond the end of the array.  Are you recommending this for the second purpose?

Comment: I recommended it because `std::cout << upperCaseArray;` assumes null-terminated string. Somehow I missed the `[i]` sitting on the end in your code. I'm wrong in this case. Sorry about that.